# Nextflow DSL2 output from different processes mixed up as input in later processes

Tags: nextflow

I have a DSL2 Nextflow pipeline that branches out to 2 `FILTER` processes. Then in the `CONCAT` process, I reuse the two previous process outputs as input. Also in the `SUMMARIZE` process, I reuse previous process ouputs as input.

I am finding that when I run the pipeline with 2 or more pairs of fastq samples, that the inputs are mixed up.

For example, at the `CONCAT` step, I end up concating the `bwa_2_ch` output of one pair of fastq samples with the `filter_1_ch` of another pair of fastq samples instead of samples with the same pair_id.

I believe am not writing the `workflow { }` channels and inputs entirely correctly the workflow runs through the steps properly without mixing samples. But I am not sure how to define the inputs so that there is no mix up.

```
//trimmomatic read trimming
process TRIM {

    tag "trim ${pair_id}"   

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/$pair_id/trim_results"

    input:
    tuple val(pair_id), path(reads) 

    output:
    tuple val(pair_id), path("trimmed_${pair_id}_...")

    script:
    """
    """
}


//bwa alignment
process BWA_1 {

    tag "align-1 ${pair_id}f"

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/$pair_id/..."

    input:
    tuple val(pair_id), path(reads)
    path index

    output:
    tuple val(pair_id), path("${pair_id}_...}")

    script:
    """
    """
}

process FILTER_1 {

    tag "filter ${pair_id}"

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/$pair_id/filter_results"

    input:
    tuple val(pair_id), path(reads)

    output:
    tuple val(pair_id), 
    path("${pair_id}_...")

    script:
    """
    """
}

process FILTER_2 {

    tag "filter ${pair_id}"

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/$pair_id/filter_results"

    input:
    tuple val(pair_id), path(reads)

    output:
    tuple val(pair_id), 
    path("${pair_id}_...")

    script:
    """
    """
}

//bwa alignment
process BWA_2 {

    tag "align-2 ${pair_id}"

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/$pair_id/bwa_2_results"

    input:
    tuple val(pair_id), path(reads)
    path index

    output:
    tuple val(pair_id), path("${pair_id}_...}")

    script:
    """
    """
}


//concatenate pf and non_human reads
process CONCAT{

    tag "concat ${pair_id}"

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/$pair_id"

    input:
    tuple val(pair_id), path(program_reads)
    tuple val(pair_id), path(pf_reads)

    output:
    tuple val(pair_id), path("${pair_id}_...")

    script:
    """
    """
}

//summary
process SUMMARY{

    tag "summary ${pair_id}"

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/$pair_id"

    input:
    tuple val(pair_id), path(trim_reads)
    tuple val(pair_id), path(non_human_reads)

    output:
    file("summary_${pair_id}.csv")

    script:
    """
    """
}

workflow {
    Channel
        .fromFilePairs(params.reads, checkIfExists: true)
        .set {read_pairs_ch}

    // trim reads
    trim_ch = TRIM(read_pairs_ch)

    // map to pf genome
    bwa_1_ch = BWA_1(trim_ch, params.pf_index)

    // filter mapped reads
    filter_1_ch = FILTER_1(bwa_1_ch)
    filter_2_ch = FILTER_2(bwa_1_ch)

    // map to pf and human genome
    bwa_2_ch = BWA_2(filter_2_ch, params.index)

    // concatenate non human reads
    concat_ch = CONCAT(bwa_2_ch,filter_1_ch)

    // summarize
    summary_ch = SUMMARY(trim_ch,concat_ch)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix-ups like this usually occur when a process erroneously receives two or more [queue](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel) channels. Most of the time, what you want is one queue channel and one or more [value](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) channels when you require [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-multiple-input-channels). Here, I'm not sure exactly what *pair_id* would be bound to, but it likely won't be what you expect:

```
input:
tuple val(pair_id), path(program_reads)
tuple val(pair_id), path(pf_reads)
```

What you want to do is replace the above with:

```
input:
tuple val(pair_id), path(program_reads), path(pf_reads)
```

And then use the [join](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join) operator to create the required inputs. For example:

```
workflow {

    Channel
        .fromFilePairs( params.reads, checkIfExists: true )
        .set { read_pairs_ch }

    pf_index = file( params.pf_index )
    bwa_index = file( params.bwa_index )

    // trim reads
    trim_ch = TRIM( read_pairs_ch )

    // map to pf genome
    bwa_1_ch = BWA_1( trim_ch, pf_index)

    // filter mapped reads
    filter_1_ch = FILTER_1(bwa_1_ch)
    filter_2_ch = FILTER_2(bwa_1_ch)

    // map to pf and human genome
    bwa_2_ch = BWA_2(filter_2_ch, bwa_index)

    // concatenate non human reads
    concat_ch = bwa_2_ch \
        | join( filter_1_ch ) \
        | CONCAT

    // summarize
    summary_ch = trim_ch \
        | join( concat_ch ) \
        | SUMMARY
}
```